# How to Install/Use Jekyll Plugins in GitHubPages?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I've created a GitHubPage together with Jekyll, and currently I'm trying to use some of the basic plugins that are available. So far nothing fancy, I'm using the whitelisted plugins, specifically [this](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank) one. It opens links in new tabs, which isn't supported by default in `Markdown`.

So far, I've created the site using `myusername.github.io` repo, cloned it to local, and created a basic site using `jekyll new .` as is instructed [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/). Then I pushed all changes to GitHub and it's all working fine.

Then, to install the above mentioned plugin, I followed the steps mentioned in the help section, namely, these things:

---

```
Add the following to your site's Gemfile

gem 'jekyll-target-blank'

and add the following to your site's _config.yml

plugins:
  - jekyll-target-blank
```

---

Also, note that by default the `Gemfile` has the following section with the instructions below:

```
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.3"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
# gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
```

So I changed the `Gemfile` as it's instructed there and ran `bundle update github-pages`.

### Now my `Gemfile` looks like this in full:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
# gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.3"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
  gem 'jekyll-target-blank'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0" if Gem.win_platform?
```

Note that I've commented/uncommented the proper sections.

### And my `_config.yml` looks like this:

```
title: xxxxxx
email: xxxxxx
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  xxxxxx.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com

github_username:  xxxxxx
instagram_username: xxxxxx

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-target-blank
```

Then I did a

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

to locally run it at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/` and the plugin works fine. By clicking a link written as below it opens the link in a new tab as it should.

```
[LinkText](link)
```

However, when I push it all to GitHub, the plugin doesn't work. It still opens the link on the same tab.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jekyll: How to use custom plugins with GitHub pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215356/jekyll-how-to-use-custom-plugins-with-github-pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of Jekyll Target Blank. GH Pages only support some plugins https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/. I have requested for this plugin to become supported but they their response was a maybe.

Comment: You can try hosting on Netlify, they have a free plan and my plugin will work there. Otherwise, you can also use Firebase by Google. You can get free credits when you sign up for GCP and then set up a firebase website.

Comment: thanks! So this means I've done things right on my part? I will try those hosting plans too.

Comment: Yes you did. This plugin works on Jekyll but as mentioned GH Pages only allow their own plugins at the moment. This is reasonable because developers can push malicious code and affect all GH users. NOte that on Firebase, you will need to push the _site contents as opposed to building it on the remote server. Netlify is a lot easier to set up but I don't know how it works for free accounts. I manage a client's site on their but it's on a premium subscription.

Comment: Thanks! For now I'm committed to GitHubPages, so hopefully they'll add your plugin as it's super convenient. But will think of moving as well.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub pages uses Kramdown, the default markdown processor in Jekyll 3. You can do this with Kramdown:

`[link](url){:target="_blank"}`

It'll open the link in a new tab, it works on my blog on GitHub pages.

If you are using the latest GitHub pages version it should work for you, too.

If this is not working, you can always use plain HTML in your markdown files and add the links like that with target _blank.

Comment: WOW didn't know about that, it's working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: what language is the part between the curly braces "{}" ? It looks like jinja2 but I've seen a language called "Liquid" referenced in the Jekyll docs, so perhaps it's that.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, there is a better and straightforward solve to use custom plugins on Github Pages using Github Actions. All the steps are documented on the official page of Jekyll: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/github-actions/. Reproducing the steps from the article above here:

1. Go to the **Settings** tab on your repository.

   1. Under **Code and automation**, click **Pages** (last option).
   2. Change **Source** under **Build and deployment** from **Deploy from a branch** to **GitHub Actions**.
2. Go to the **Actions** tab on your repository.

   1. Start a **New workflow** and search for **Jekyll**.
   2. Click **Configure** under the **Jekyll** workflow (NOT **GitHub Pages Jekyll** workflow).
   3. Review the change and click **Commit changes**.

On pushing any local changes onto the default branch, the action will be triggered and the build will start.

The build might fail because of an error as below:

```
 Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/cache/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
```

To fix this, place the line `exclude: [vendor]` in `_config.yml`. More discussion here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5267.