# Jekyll: How to use custom plugins with GitHub pages?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

It turns out that custom ruby plugins don't work on GitHub pages because of [security concerns](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5265).

I'm trying to add a plugin ([this one](https://github.com/bdesham/reading_time)) to the `_plugins` folder of my Jekyll project, but when I deploy it to GitHub it is ignored.

**Question:** Is there a way to workaround this? Has anyone found a solution?

**Note:** Obviously I can generate html files locally and commit them to my repository. But that's not what I want.

Comment: You can use an hosting like Netlify.

Comment: Move to Gitlab pages today!

Comment: Hey Sasha, would you consider accept an answer? [yegor256's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56704479/2989289) was helpful to my search

Answer (score 7):

### Without a plugin

A reading time script does not require a plugin. I have created a collection of scripts that can be added without using a plugin. You can find them [here](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugins/). [A reading time script](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/reading-time-indicator/) is one of them.

Here you find the code:

```
{% capture words %}
{{ content | number_of_words | minus: 180 }}
{% endcapture %}
{% unless words contains '-' %}
{{ words | plus: 180 | divided_by: 180 | append: ' minutes to read' }}
{% endunless %}
```

Note that this code contains only Liquid and no Ruby. Therefore it can be used in your layout or in an include (without a plugin).

### Optimizing the script

Suppose you have something like this:

```
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<code>lorem ipsum</code>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<code>lorem ipsum</code>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Then you could remove the above code blocks like this:

```
{% assign preprocessed_content=post.content | replace: '<p>', '__p__' %}
{% assign preprocessed_content=preprocessed_content | replace: '</p>', '__/p__' %}
{% assign truncated_content=preprocessed_content | strip_html %}
{% assign cleaned_content=truncated_content | replace: '__p__', '<p>' %}
{% assign cleaned_content=cleaned_content | replace: '__/p__', '</p>' %}
```

Ofcourse this can be extended to support more tags.

### Using the plugin anyway

If you REALLY want to use a plugin you can let your local machine or CloudCannon build your site and push the result to Github Pages. See also: https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/using-jekyll-plugins/

Comment: Thank you. `number_of_words` was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately it doesn't satisfy my needs. My articles often contain code blocks but `number_of_words` doesn't provide any mechanism to filter page content. Excluding `code`, `pre`,  `script` etc might help but it is currently not possible. That's why for some articles it shows 2-3times more words than needed. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You could try to split your content on code blocks. Are you sure that you can read code faster than normal words? I would say the opposite is true.

Comment: It is not about performance. I don't want my code to be included to words count, it doesn't make sense. For instance, this article of mine http://sashashpota.com/2018/10/30/why-you-need-to-implement-a-plugin.html contains around 800 words, but `number_of_words` shows 1400 words as it counts code blocks as well.

Comment: No, it is not about performance. It is about the speed at which humans read text and code. I do not think that you can read code faster than normal words/text. Code blocks are no images and should not be considered as such (IMO).

Comment: I see your point and probably it works in many cases. But I think that in my case a user doesn't need to read the code word-by-word, they might just copy and paste it. Or in case if there is a log it is also nor required to read it, you can just quickly go through. But there is more than just code - if I remove images from my article `number_of_words` shows 25 symbols less. Did I remove some words? I guess not. I think `number_of_words` is good for some very basic cases, but not in my case. At the same time the plugin I mentioned in the question covers all corner cases. I wish I could use it.

Comment: Only 25 characters? Probably in one word. That adds less than 1 second to the reading time. I think you are trying very hard to find a reason to use a plugin. However, you can easily use plugins if you let your local machine or CloudCannon build your site/plugin code and push the result to Github Pages. See also: https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/using-jekyll-plugins/

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `replace` and `strip_html`. I solved my problem using your suggestion https://github.com/Shpota/shpota.github.io/commit/36b6cc3cfc3041456f5a1da8ee82e404f3444f47
It is not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use your custom plugins, you have to "build" your site locally and then deploy it to the `gh-pages` branch yourself, as a collection of HTML, CSS and other files (not Markdown files anymore). You may want to try [`jgd`](https://github.com/yegor256/jekyll-github-deploy) command line to to help you do it all automatically. Just install it and then run:

```
$ jgd
```

The site will be packaged and then deployed to the `gh-pages` branch of your repo. More about it in this blog post of mine: [Deploy Jekyll to GitHub Pages](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/24/jekyll-github-deploy.html)

Answer (score 2):

A better and straightforward solve to use custom plugins on Github Pages is using Github Actions. All the steps are documented on the official page of Jekyll: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/github-actions/. Reproducing the steps from the article above here:

1. Go to the **Settings** tab on your repository.

   1. Under **Code and automation**, click **Pages** (last option).
   2. Change **Source** under **Build and deployment** from **Deploy from a branch** to **GitHub Actions**.
2. Go to the **Actions** tab on your repository.

   1. Start a **New workflow** and search for **Jekyll**.
   2. Click **Configure** under the **Jekyll** workflow (NOT **GitHub Pages Jekyll** workflow).
   3. Review the change and click **Commit changes**.

On pushing any local changes onto the default branch, the action will be triggered and the build will start.

The build might fail because of an error as below:

```
 Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/cache/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
```

To fix this, place the line `exclude: [vendor]` in `_config.yml`. More discussion here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5267.

Comment: This is the preferred method and works.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't what a local solution because it's time consuming, you could automate a process so that when you push changes to master it will automatically build your website locally and push the changes to the `gh-pages` branch.

You can achieve this by creating a `pre-push` hook in your repo (`.git/hooks/pre-push`) with the following content:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# If any command fails in the bellow script, exit with error
set -e

# Set the name of the folder that will be created in the parent
# folder of your repo folder, and which will temporarily
# hold the generated content.
temp_folder="_gh-pages-temp"

# Make sure our main code runs only if we push the master branch
if [ "$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == "master" ]; then
    # Store the last commit message from master branch
    last_message=$(git show -s --format=%s master)

    # Build our Jekyll site
    jekyll build

    # Move the generated site in our temp folder
    mv _site ../${temp_folder}

    # Checkout the gh-pages branch and clean it's contents
    git checkout gh-pages
    rm -rf *

    # Copy the site content from the temp folder and remove the temp folder
    cp -r ../${temp_folder}/* .
    rm -rf ../${temp_folder}

    # Commit and push our generated site to GitHub
    git add -A
    git commit -m "Built \`$last_message\`"
    git push

    # Go back to the master branch
    git checkout master
else
    echo "Not master branch. Skipping build"
fi
```

For more details please [see my blog post](https://surdu.me/2020/02/04/jekyll-git-hook.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need an alternative to those plugins.

As detailed in "[Building a Series List with Hugo Shortcodes](https://realjenius.com/2017/08/07/series-list-with-hugo/)":

Ruby plugin execution is disabled altogether on Github pages:

> Plugins on GitHub Pages GitHub Pages is powered by Jekyll.
>   **However, all Pages sites are generated using the `-safe` option to disable custom plugins for security reasons**. Unfortunately, this means your plugins won’t work if you’re deploying to GitHub Pages.
>
> You can still use GitHub Pages to publish your site, **but you’ll need to convert the site locally and push the generated static files to your GitHub repository instead of the Jekyll source files**.

I understand you mention:

> Obviously I can generate html files locally and commit them to my repository. But that's not what I want.

Still, a static website generator (compatible with GitHub pages) like **[Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)** is to be considered in your case.

[R.J Lorimer](https://realjenius.com/about/) adds:

> Hugo has the concept of **[Shortcodes](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/)**, which are much like “Liquid Tags” in Jekyll.
>   Also like Jekyll, you can create custom shortcode tags.
>
> However, the major difference is that in Hugo you can create them without resorting to actually writing Go code - see [Create Your Own Shortcodes](https://gohugo.io/templates/shortcode-templates/).
>   Because Hugo uses Go Templates for rendering the pages, shortcodes can use any and all Go template functions inside of them, as well as a whole list of custom Hugo functions added to help. This makes it arguably more powerful than a liquid-template solution, but still in a template file that can be easily updated on the fly.

Plus, Hugo does [support MathJax](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#mathjax-with-hugo), as [seen in this article](http://www.latkin.org/blog/2016/08/07/better-tex-math-typesetting-in-hugo/).

Update Nov. 2018: with [Hugo 0.52](https://gohugo.io/news/0.52-relnotes/), this [tweet confirms](https://twitter.com/GoHugoIO/status/1068074313692184576) (referencing [this thread](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/hugo-0-52-released/15551/7?u=bep)):

> The **[inline shortcode](https://gohugo.io//templates/shortcode-templates/#inline-shortcodes)** is similar to the way Jekyll allows you to use Liquid tags within Markdown

Comment: Thank you for proposing an alternative solution. But I'm afraid switching from Jekyll to Hugo is even bigger pain. Alternatively I could host my blog on GitLab where custom plugins are supported.